# Can't get values from text fields from UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I used for username/password enter.
But I have problem to get values when I click on button.
This is how I make table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
                playerTextField.placeholder = @"example@gmail.com";
                playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
                playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            }
            else {
                playerTextField.placeholder = @"Required";
                playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                playerTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
            }
            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            playerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
            playerTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            playerTextField.tag = 0;

            playerTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];

        }
    }
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) { // Email & Password Section
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) { // Email
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Email";
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And this is what I have tried in button tap:

```
...
for (UITableViewCell* aCell in [self.tableView visibleCells] ) {
        UITextField* aField = (UITextField *)[aCell viewWithTag:0];
        NSLog(aField.text);
    }
..
```

This prints me just: Email Password (labels not data that I entered).
How to get entered values here?

Comment: you are assigning same tag no "0" to all the cells..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All views default their `tag` to 0.  Because of this, `[aCell viewWithTag: 0]` is returning the first view with tag zero - in this case the cell's `textLabel` - which is a `UILabel` that also responds to `.text`.  If you set the tags in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to something other than zero it should start working for you.

Comment: Hi friends, in my logic i have to add 12 textfield in tableview cell and access each textfield's text by their tag value

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can give the tag to textfield like 
 **playerTextField.tag = 115** 
and you can get view by tag like 
 **UITextField *aField = (UITextField *)[aCell viewWithTag:115];**
 and display **NSLog(@"text:%@",aField.text);**